# Cypress: custom timeout in specific should command

Tags: javascript, cypress

I need to have custom timeout in a specific `should` command in cypress. 
I have this json file which has global timeout:

```
{
  "viewportWidth": 1600,
  "defaultCommandTimeout": 10000
}
```

There is a specific case that I need a higher timeout, I would like something like this:

```
cy.get('body').should('contain','success', {timeout: 30000})
```

how do I do this? BTW, I do not want to override default command timeout, I need a specific timeout.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### tl;dr

Just pass the timeout to `get`, it will pass it down to `should`.

```js
cy.get('body', {timeout: 30000}).should('contain','success')
```

### Explanation

This is explained in [`should`'s official documentation in the Timeouts section](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/should.html#Timeouts):

> `.should()` will continue to [retry](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/retry-ability.html) its specified assertions until it times out.
>
> ```js
> cy.get('input', { timeout: 10000 }).should('have.value', '10')
> // timeout here will be passed down to the '.should()'
> // and it will retry for up to 10 secs
> ```

The technique is explained in greater detail in the [docs about timeouts](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/introduction-to-cypress.html#Timeouts).

Answer (score 4):

You probably want to move your `{timeout: 30000}` option to the parent command, like this:

```
cy.get('body', {timeout: 30000}).should('contain','success')
```

In this way the parent command's default assertions, and all subsequent assertions inherit this timeout overriding the default command timeout.
Read more here: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/introduction-to-cypress.html#Timeouts